# z-index not working as expected on hovered side nav

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have sample page here: https://jsfiddle.net/solaris_9/17dwfmap/16/

```
.area-toc a {
    position: absolute; /* Position them relative to the browser window */
    left: -120px; /* Position them outside of the screen */
    transition: 0.3s; /* Add transition on hover */
    /*padding: 2px; *//* 15px padding */
    width: 140px; /* Set a specific width */
    text-decoration: none; /* Remove underline */
    font-size: 15px; /* Increase font size */
    color: white; /* White text color */
    border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0; /* Rounded corners on the top right and bottom right side */
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #76a000;
    z-index: 99;
}
.area-toc a:hover{
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99;
}
.table-main{
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#aad69e;
    border-width:1px 1px 1px;
    z-index:9;
    position:relative;
}
```

Generally speaking, when the mouse hovers at the side nav, I want the link could be rendered in front of the table. I set the z-index of it to 99, while the table is 9, but it doesn't work.

Do you have any idea? Does it link to the flex display of the table?

Comment: use position when really needed only ;) https://jsfiddle.net/17dwfmap/18/ If you have to, then mind the positionned parents which are sibblings to calculate the z-index from there  : https://jsfiddle.net/17dwfmap/19/ z-index goes with : relative,absolute,fixed position. transform can also make it efficient.

Comment: @G-Cyr, thanks for your solution. It works. But I don't understand the logic. Can you elaborate more? for this description: Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed). As the .table-title & .table-main are relative, the z-index shall be working.

Comment: you set table on z-index:10; but , .area-toc in fixed position receive no higher value (defaut is 1) , whatever is inside will be calculated from that layer level. . z-index:99; to children will be 99 inside its container which is on level 1 ... below the table.else, do not use position elsewhere, where you do not need it. so you do not even need to (re)set the z-index to 1 (plenty enough)

Comment: an example with absolute,relative,fixed and transform with different z-index value all reset to auto when body hovered https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/yqwXXo if that helps to see and understand how it works.

Comment: @G-Cyr, thanks so much for your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem I often face too when working with z-index's. The way I workaround this is to just set the z-index of the element I want to be lower, to a negative number.

https://jsfiddle.net/17dwfmap/27/

On line 113, I changed

```
z-index:9;
```

to

```
 z-index:-10;
```

Comment: Yes, this solution solves the problem in a quite neat way. Considering the answer from @G-Gyr, if the fixed position will lead to z-index=1 as default, then, setting the table to -1 is quite reasonable. In general, both of you helped me, thanks!